# json and php question

Tags: php, javascript

I am using the following in php to return the driving distance details between 2 locations:

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover';
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
```

A JSON object is returned, i am not familiar with JSON can somebody please demonstrate how I can get the "Meters" element from this object into a string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
echo $obj->Directions->Distance->meters;
```

Comment: @brux You should know that the property name is "meters" with a lowercase "m".

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) function...

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover';
$data = json_decode(@file_get_contents($url));

echo $data->Directions->Distance->meters." meters";
```

Result:

```
123561 meters
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [online json Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from%3aLondon%20to%3aDover) you can call JSON.parse in javascript to parse the string php output to a javascript object.

```
var json = {}; // parsed json object

var meters = json.Directions.Distance.meters; // is '123561'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode`. [JSON Decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover';
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->meters;
```